# select data betwenn two date

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm working in Hive on data set below

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
code             dateJ                 capa
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
1988           2015-08-22               23
0470           2015-07-26               455
...             .....                   ...
5884           2015-08-01               54
4587           2015-06-05              100
```

I would like to pick up "code" from the table between two dates. query below works :

```
SELECT code FROM tabl WHERE dateJ BETWEEN '2015-06-05' AND '2015-08-22'
```

But when I use nested/sub-queries I doesn't work :

```
SELECT code FROM tabl WHERE dateJ BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(dateJ) FROM tabl) and (SELECT MAX(dateJ) FROM tabl)
```

Does any body could help on how I can fix the problem (with the second query). hive don't support subqueries.

Thx

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.  Here it is :

```
select code from tabl, 
(select min(dateJ) mindate, max(dateJ) maxdate from tabl) tmp 
where dateJ between tmp.mindate and tmp.maxdate
```

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is [not supported in Hive](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries), unfortunately.  You can only use a select statement in the where clause in conjunction with `IN`, `NOT IN`, `EXISTS`, and `NOT EXISTS`.  If you can find a way to construct the functionality you need using those and joins, then that's the way to go.

Comment: Charlie, you mean that IN, NOT IN, EXISTS, NOT EXISTS are also not supported??

Comment: They are supported.  >, <, ==, etc are not supported.